# Laravel form inputs - how to set maxlength

Tags: php, forms, laravel, input, maxlength

Maximal length of HTML inputs can be set by: 
`<input type="text" name="" maxlength="10">`
Is there a way how to set maxlength of form input when creating inputs in Laravel way?

```
{{ Form::text('name', null, array('placeholder' => '')) }}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
{{ Form::text('name', null, array('placeholder' => '','maxlength' => 10 )) }}
```

Works with the **Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit)**

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I can still type unlimited character count.

Comment: Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit)

Comment: oh, I was testing another input, sorry.

Comment: I can do it in 5 minutes

Answer (score 5):

You can also check in validation as follow. For more details, you can take a look in [validation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation)

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    array('name' => 'name'),
    array('name' => 'required|max:5')
);
```